# SQL error 42803: I shouldn't be getting this error, what's going on?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my first post here on stack overflow.  Every other time I've needed something from here, someone else had already asked the question.  I couldn't find any questions quite like this, so I though I'd make a new post.

I'm having a bit of an issue with a SQL query, and the error code doesn't make much sense to me.  The query is as follows:

```
SELECT customer.account as "Account", customer.name as "Customer Name", sum(slpayment.payment_amount) as "Payment Amount", slpayment.reference, max(date(slpayment.payment_date)) as "Payment Date",  
CASE WHEN customer.userchk1 = '1' then 'B' else ' Y' END as type  
FROM customer  
INNER JOIN slpayment ON customer.company = slpayment.company and  
customer.account = slpayment.account  
WHERE slpayment.sales_period='11'
```

This query is flagging up SQL error 42803: "ERROR: column "customer.account" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

I am familiar with this error and have managed to resolve it on other queries.  However, what I fail to understand is why I'm getting this error.  The query in question does not have a GROUP BY clause anywhere in the function.  I had a look at other people who asked similar questions here on stack overflow, but all their queries did include a GROUP BY, and therefore it made sense why they were getting the error.  I'm just at a loss as to why I'm having trouble here.

Thanks in advance for having a look!

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Yes, you should be getting that error message.  First rule of debugging : assume that ***you*** made the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `group by` clause and apply all columns except aggregated columns

```
SELECT customer.account as "Account", customer.name as "Customer Name", sum(slpayment.payment_amount) as "Payment Amount", slpayment.reference, max(date(slpayment.payment_date)) as "Payment Date", CASE WHEN customer.userchk1 = '1' then 'B' else ' Y' END as type 
FROM customer INNER JOIN slpayment 
ON customer.company = slpayment.company and customer.account = slpayment.account 
WHERE slpayment.sales_period='11'
group by customer.account , customer.name ,slpayment.reference,customer.userchk1
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast!  Thanks for the advice, I added the clause and it's working perfectly now!

Comment: Yeah, I was going to but it said I had to wait, so I moved on to do a few other things and came back to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It is mandatory to use `group by` cluase if you use aggregate function like `sum,avg,count,min,max` ,as a result though you have not used `group by` in your query but if you used aggregate function in your query postgrey engine will suggest you to use that in your query if you have any non aggregate column in selection

[Read aggregate function docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-agg.html)

so  your query would be like below

```
SELECT customer.account as "Account", customer.name as "Customer Name", sum(slpayment.payment_amount) as "Payment Amount", slpayment.reference, max(date(slpayment.payment_date)) as "Payment Date",  
CASE WHEN customer.userchk1 = '1' then 'B' else ' Y' END as type  
FROM customer  
INNER JOIN slpayment ON customer.company = slpayment.company and  
customer.account = slpayment.account  
WHERE slpayment.sales_period='11'
group by customer.account,customer.name,slpayment.reference
```

Comment: I think you mean "use an aggregate function *alongside non aggregated values* in the select clause".

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I hadn't realized that SUM() was what was causing the error to occur.  Thanks for the advice, I'll keep it in mind.  Between yourself and fa06, I've got this sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a lateral join:

```
SELECT c.account, c.name as "Customer Name", 
       p."Payment Amount", p.reference, 
       max(date(p.payment_date)) as "Payment Date",
       (case when c.userchk1 = '1' then 'B' else ' Y' end) as type 
FROM customer c CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT p.reference,
             sum(p.payment_amount) as "Payment Amount",
             max(date(p.payment_date)) as "Payment Date"
      FROM slpayment p
      WHERE c.company = p.company AND 
            c.account = p.account AND
            p.sales_period = '11'
     ) p;
```

Presumably, you are not actually aggregating rows from `customers` -- just the data from the payments table.  If so, this should have better performance.

Comment: Does this answer imply that whenever there are two or more rows with the same value in any given field, SQL expects you to group by that field? What if I don't want to use an aggregate function but list all of the rows with identical values on that given column?